# May I use "wtf" with a non-question? -- "wtf I just watched."

Tags: transitivity, do-support, exclamatives

I know that usually people write:

> "wtf did I just watch?"

But is "wtf I just watched" a correct English sentence as "I just watched" is a correct English sentence and adding *wtf* should not make such difference.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you please give more [context](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)? Like, in what situations did you read this?

Comment: Calling _i just watched_ a "correct English sentence" is a tenuous claim.

Comment: He was in trouble. Why didn't you help him? Ans. "I just watched." *wtf* optional.

Comment: None of y'all are understanding the original question, which is 'Can someone use "WTF" as a NON-question?'. The answer is 'yes' - it all depends on how you say it.

Comment: @user3169 optional, as a prefixed interrogative. *WTF?(!) I just watched.* Exclamation optimal.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not correct.
If you expand it, you get "What the fuck did I just watch?", a question.
Therefore "What the fuck I just watched?" isn't correct.

Comment: But why isn't it correct? Expanding WTF doesn't change anything if the asker doesn't understand "just watched".

Comment: Then again, why not expand it to _WTF **have** I just watched_? Adding _did_ messes up the grammar, adding _have_ fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

> But is "wtf I just watched" a correct English sentence as "I just watched" is a correct English sentence and adding wtf should not make such difference.

No, what follows *what the X* (X can be a number of words), needs to be a form of *to be* or emphatic verb starting with a form of *to do* - like  interrogative sentences in general.

> Wtf is happening?
>
> Wtf did he say to me?

Answer (score 1):

> WTF did I just watch?

Is a grammatically correct statement.

> WTF I just watched.

is not.  If you have heard someone say this, they propably said:

> WTF, I just watched...

Using WTF as an interjection, then describing the cause for their distress.  For example, I could be watching some sports game, and exclaim:

> WTF, I just watched that player cheat!

after seeing a player break a rule and not get penalized.

So "WTF" can sometimes be used with a non-question, depending on how it is used.  If it is used as a question (which, grammatically, it is) "WTF" cannot be added to a non-question.  If "WTF" is used as an exclaimation/interjection followed by a non-question (as in my sports example), it is grammatically correct.

Comment: Except I would understand *WTF* itself to be a question, perhaps rhetorical, so my punctuation would be *WTF?! I just watched...*

Comment: @AlanCarmack | "WTF?! I just watched..." is correct.  A comma has multiple uses, one of which is seperating a interjection from the rest of a sentence.  I just chose to use a comma as opposed to "?!" or an interrobang (‽).